# how to fix Angular Unsupported Engines warning?

Tags: angular, npm, dependencies

I'm having problems in my angular project with errors Unsupported Engines like:

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular-devkit/architect@0.1102.19',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 10.13.0', npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6', yarn: '>= 1.13.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.15.0', npm: '8.5.5' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
```

for angular-devkit/architect the configuration in package.json is:

```
"node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect": {
      "version": "0.1102.19",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular-devkit/architect/-/architect-0.1102.19.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-5Opv6H+XyCkuQvQ1jsxw416YqMDPX3dVonMarFGBPLBe8YEXLRTJ60dvmuLsLpWk6ccTd3XiNT7WEJy4ctDc2Q==",
      "dev": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/core": "11.2.19",
        "rxjs": "6.6.3"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">= 10.13.0",
        "npm": "^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6",
        "yarn": ">= 1.13.0"
      }
    }
```

$ node --version
v16.15.0

$ npm --version
8.5.5

**After Angular update**
$ npm --version
8.5.5

$ node --version
v16.15.0

$ ng v

```
Angular CLI: 14.2.1 
Node: 16.15.0 
Package Manager: npm 8.5.5 
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 14.2.0 ... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms ...   
material, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                       n   Version
--------------------------------------------------------- 
@angular-devkit/architect         0.1402.1 
@angular-devkit/build-angular     14.2.1 
@angular-devkit/core              14.2.1 
@angular-devkit/schematics        14.2.1 
@angular/cli                      14.2.1 
@schematics/angular               14.2.1 
rxjs                              6.6.7
```

I don't understand how to solve it.
I run `nmp install`, `npm audit fix --force`, `npm update`, ..etc, but nothing seems to fix these errors.

Comment: we see your node version what is your Angular CLI version?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to install dependencies using an unsupported npm version.

In the package.json , the npm version is specified to show a warning when the user doesn't have the required npm version installed.
the required version is "^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6" but you have 8.5.5 installed

So to fix that :

**Solution 1 :**

you need to install the right  [npm version](https://xpertuto.com/angular-3-steps-to-install-angular-environment/)  (^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6 )

**Solution 2 :**

you can disable the engine check by creating a .npmrc file in your root project, and you specify that you want to turn off the engine check for the project by using :

```
engine-strict=false
```

Comment: thanks, i downgraded npm to 7.5 with npm install -g npm@7.5
 and that fixed the problem.

Comment: Good , You welcome :)